# MarkLogic Server's database reindexing is fast, but is there a way to make it even faster?

Tags: marklogic

When I am making rapid changes to a database that requires reindexing, such as adding new range indexes, there are times when I find myself waiting for reindexing to complete before I can make use of a new index, in cases when I have 100s of 1000s of loaded documents, and I can see that only 25% of my CPU is in use--is there a way to speed up reindexing, perhaps by allocating more resources to the job? The database's `reindexer throttle` setting is already `5`, so it's working its hardest, but can we make it work even harder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, check if your disk is swamped.  You say your CPU is 25% idle.  How's your disk?  Maybe you're limited by storage not CPU, in which case faster storage will speed your reindex.

If that's not it, make sure you have enough forests.  The advice today is to have 6 primary forests on a modern server.  That ensures enough parallelism, so you actually use all your hardware.

(Removing these bottlenecks will speed ingest and query as well.)

Comment: I should have mentioned that this instance is for local development on a MBP. It's SSD/Flash, I'd have to look up the specs. It's more like 75% is idle. I didn't check on the number of threads. I'm afraid I didn't realize that forests had any relationship to multithreaded processing, I think I should read the pertinent sections in the administrator's guide, assuming that information is covered. 160K documents and only one forest. Thanks for your answer, it's been most helpful.